# Searching Array in PHP and return results

Tags: php, arrays, search, calendar

Can't find quite the right answer so hope someone can help. Basically want to create an array and then return the results from a search e.g.

```
$tsql = "SELECT date, staffid, ID,status, eventid, auditid from maincalendar";  

$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ); 
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql , $params, $options);      
$calarray=array();
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
    $rowresult = array();
    $rowresult["status"] = $row['status'];
    $rowresult["eventid"] = $row['eventid'];
    $rowresult["caldate"] = $row['date'];
    $rowresult["staffid"] = $row['staffid'];
    $rowresult["ID"] = $row['ID'];
    $rowresult["auditid"] = $row['auditid'];
    $calarray[] = $rowresult; 
}
```

I would then like to search for values matching 'caldate' and 'staffid' and return the associated entry in $calarray

Comment: can't you change the SQL to have `WHERE caldate = ? AND/OR staffid = ?`?

Comment: do you know that you can do $calarray[] = $row instead and save 7 lines of code? xd

Comment: hi - basically trying to create a simple calendar with a list of staff on left and then dates going from left to right in table - I then want to search each date and if staff is booked show the event in that corresponding cell. Works fine if I run a query everytime for each cell but slow so looking for faster method. Thought if I could do one SELECT statement and put it into array then query array each time it might speed it up?

Comment: UnholyRanger - that is right, and that's what I am doing now but 60 staff in table and running query for every day seems to be taking a while so looking for solution to speed up!

Comment: aleation - no I didn't - can you tell I am a noob!? that is awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following,

- Fetch all data needed for the current month you are showing, using `col BETWEEN x AND y`
- Add them to a array in PHP, with `staffid` and `caldate` as key

Something like so;

```
$calarray[$row['staffid'] . '-' . $row['date']][] = $row;
```

Not sure if a single staffid/date combination can have one or more events per day, if not you can remove the `[]`

To check if we have information for a specific staffid/date combination, use `isset`

```
if (isset($calarray[$staffid . '-' . $mydate]) { ... }
```

Comment: That is beautiful! So if I wanted to return say 'status' from the result - how do I get at that value? Thanks

Comment: $calarray[$staffid . '-' . $mydate]['status'], or if you go with the extra `[]` $calarray[$staffid . '-' . $mydate][_index_]['status']

Comment: `print_r` and `var_dump` is your friend

Comment: Thanks Hank so much, this works perfectly and is ten times faster on loading calendar now - plus only queries database the once and not 31(days) x 60 staff = over 1,800 times! Every day is a school day.... :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$matches = array();
$caldate = //your desired date;
$staffid = //your desired id;

foreach($calarray as $k => $v){
   if(in_array($caldate, $v['caldate']) && in_array($staffid, $v['staffid'])){
      $matches[] = $calarray[$k];
   }
}
```

$matches should be and array with all the results you wanted.

---

also:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
   $rowresult = array();
   $rowresult["status"] = $row['status'];
   $rowresult["eventid"] = $row['eventid'];
   $rowresult["caldate"] = $row['date'];
   $rowresult["staffid"] = $row['staffid'];
   $rowresult["ID"] = $row['ID'];
   $rowresult["auditid"] = $row['auditid'];
   $calarray[] = $rowresult; 
}
```

can be shortened into:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
    $calarray[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code snipplet solves your problem.
I am not a PHP programmer, so no warrenty.

```
function searchInArray($array, $keyword) {
    for($i=0;$i<array.length();$i++) {
        if(stristr($array[$i], $keyword) === FALSE) {
            return "Found ".$keyword." in array[".$i."]";
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you know there is a native php function that does the function you created ? xD http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 0):

Add indexes to the fields you're going to query, and then move the search to the sql query. You can also make simple filtering inside the loop. So you'll be populating several arrays instead of one, based on the search you need.